# SignatureDoesNotMatch on GET request to pre-signed URL (hellosign)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify, hellosign-api

i am attempting to grab a pdf file for e-signature using pre-signed URLs. i use Amplify Storage to generate the URL. then i provide the URL to the HelloSign function to bring the file into the embedding window. i am able to open the document using `window.open` but this other method brings the `SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.` error.

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

```js
key: string = 'bucketname/path/to/file.pdf'
expires: number = 60

const url = await Storage.get(key, {
  level: 'public',
  cacheControl: 'no-cache',
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  ContentType: 'application/pdf',
  expires: 60,
  customPrefix: {
    public: '',
    protected: '',
    private: '',
  },
})

hellosign.open(url, {
  clientId,
  skipDomainVerification: true,
})
```

one fix i found on Github was to include the `signatureVersion` when initializing the `S3` class instance using the SDK. i am not using the SDK however, so i tried providing it when configuring Amplify like so:

```js
AWSS3: {
  bucket,
  region,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
},
```

needless to say it did not fix the issue. i could not find any references to this in the docs, as the `Amplify.configure` function takes `any` in their docs.

i tried clicking the pre-signed URL and was able to download the doc without issue. i inspected the request and saw the correct headers that match the outgoing request originating from `hellosign.open`. any ideas what i can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hellosign.open()`  is only expected to load embedded URLs. These would be URLs returned from requests to the following endpoints:

- /embedded/sign_url/ (sign URL - embedded signing)
- /template/create_embedded_draft (edit URL - embedded template creation)
- /embedded/edit_url/ (edit URL - embedded template editing)
- /unclaimed_draft/create_embedded (claim URL embedded requesting)
- /unclaimed_draft/create_embedded_with_template (claim URL embedded requesting)

If you'd like to collect signatures on a document in an iframe on your site, embedded signing will likely be what you're looking for. In that case, you'd want to create your signature request with a request to:

/signature_request/create_embedded

and then use the URL you're creating via Amplify Storage as the value of the file_url[] request parameter.

Once you've created your request, locate the signature ID for your signer in the response object, and use that in a request to /embedded/sign_url/

This will return a sign URL that you can load using `hellosign.open()`.